# Alteração no texto do botão com a linguagem Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de ficar alterando o texto do botão toda vez que eu clicar nele. Consigo alterar o texto somente uma vez. Toda vez que for clicado quero que apareça ligar lampada/desligar lampada.

[image: [![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EckA5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Você precisaria de uma variável auxiliar com um valor booleano para alterar entre ligado e desligado. Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

```
class MyButton(Button):
    __status = False

    def change(self):
        self.__status = not self.__status
        self.text = "Desligar" if self.__status else "Ligar"

class App(App):

    def build(self):

        button = MyButton(text = "Ligar", font_size = 40)
        button.on_release = button.change
        return button
```

No exemplo acima, o atributo `__status` alterna entre `True` e `False` a cada chamada do método `change()` e depois o texto do botão é definido de acordo com o valor desse atributo.